# sql pls-00103 code errors

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER verifier_salle_pavillon
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON Salle
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (:NEW.id_salle = (select *
                    from Salle
                    where id_pavillon = :OLD.id_pavillon;)) 
THEN
DELETE FROM Salle
WHERE id_salle = :NEW.id_salle;
END IF;
END;
/
```

And I get this Error:

```
4/42     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the
 following:
 . ( ) * @ % & - + / at mod remainder rem with <exposant (**)>
 and or group having intersect minus start union where connect
 || indicator multiset
 The symbol ";" was ignored.
```

The error is at line 4? What's wrong with BEGIN?

What is wrong with that trigger?
I just want to delete the row when there is already a row having the same id_pavillon and id_groupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parsing problem is the semicolon in this part:

```
IF (:NEW.id_salle = (select *
                    from Salle
                    where id_pavillon = :OLD.id_pavillon;)) 
--------------------------------------------------------^
```

I should say "the first problem".  The code `= (select *` is highly unorthodox and quite likely to produce errors.

You can write this without the `if`:

```
DELETE FROM Salle
WHERE id_salle = :NEW.id_salle AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Salle WHERE id_pavillon = :OLD.id_pavillon);
```

This might require another condition, depending on what you intend by the original `if` condition.